# A ship slows down its speed according to the water resistance, which is proportional to the ship speed.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> A ship slows down its speed according to the water resistance, which is proportional to the ship speed. The initial speed of the ship is $2m/sec$, the speed after $4$ seconds is $1m/sec$.
> Use a differential equation to solve the following questions:
> When is the speed $0.25 m/sec$? How great can the distance covered by the ship become before it comes to a complete standstill?

**My answer :**

According to the question :
$$ -\frac{dv}{dt} = kv$$ where $k$ is a constant.

Solving it we get :
$$ \ln v = -kt + c$$ where $c$ is an integrating constant.

Now given that : $v(0) = 2, v(4) = 1$.

Therefore, $$ \ln 2 = 0 + c \\
              \implies c = \ln 2$$
Thus, $$ \ln v = -kt + \ln 2 \\
         \implies 0 = -4k + \ln 2$$      [putting $v(4) = 1$]       $$\therefore k = \frac{1}{4} \ln 2$$

Therefore, $$ \ln v = - (\frac{1}{4} \ln 2)t + \ln 2$$

Now, let $t$ be the time when $v=0.25$. Then we have -
$$ \ln 0.25 = (\frac{1}{4} \ln 2)t + \ln 2 \\
   \implies t = 4 \Big(\frac{\ln 2 - \ln 0.25}{\ln 2}\Big) = 12$$

This is the far I got to but I cannot find the next answer. The problem for me is that if I write $v= \frac{dx}{dt}$ in the equation of $v$ then I'll get another integrating constant, which I can't figure out the value of.

Anyone please help.

Comment: "it comes to a complete standstill."  So when is $v(t) = 0$?  Then you have a *definite* integral from $t = 0$ to the standstill time.  (You may find that the standstill time is unreasonably large.  The resulting improper integral still has a definite value.)

Comment: @Eric since theres $\ln$ in the equation of $v$ then yes it'll yield the time to be unreasonably large but how can I even form that definite integral? Can you please show me?

Comment: What is the difficulty in writing $\int_0^\infty v(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$, the displacement from time $0$ until the boat comes to a complete standstill?

Comment: I still can't see how writing $\int_0^\infty v(t) \,\mathrm{d}t$ will give me the time. :(

Comment: "How great can the distance covered by the ship" is not a time.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I got confused. And for the justification of the upper limit to be $\infty$ is that if we plug in $v=0$ in the equation, it tells that $t \to \infty$, right?

Comment: Best would be to solve for $v(t)$, so you can explicitly show that the velocity is a decreasing exponential in time.  Then it is immediate that the velocity is positive at all times, so the requested distance is only attained in the limit of infinite time.

Comment: Okay thank you.

Comment: @Eric I've done that. Can you please confirm if the answer is $11.54m$?

Comment: I do get $$\frac{8}{\ln(2)} \,\mathrm{m}  \text{,}  $$ which is compatible with the approximation you write.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I got. Also, what should I do with the question here, should I delete it or post an answer?

Comment: Posting an answer seems like a good idea to me.  It might help someone in the future.